# If $\alpha= \frac{\pi}{7}$ and also if $\frac{3- \tan^2 (\alpha)}{1 - \tan^2 (\alpha)} = \lambda \cos(\alpha)$. Then find $\lambda$.

Tags: trigonometry

Given that

$$\frac{3- \tan^2 \left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)}{1 - \tan^2 \left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)} = \lambda \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)$$

Then find the value of $\lambda$.

Comment: What do you mean? You just need to devid by $\cos \frac \pi 7$ to find $\lambda$!

Answer (score 4):

Notice, setting the value of $\alpha=\pi/7$, one can simplify LHS as follows   $$LHS=\frac{3-\tan^2(\alpha)}{1-\tan^2(\alpha)}$$
$$=\frac{3-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7}}{1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7}}$$

$$=\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7}+2}{1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7}}$$
$$=1+\frac{2}{1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7}}$$
$$=1+\frac{2\tan\frac{\pi}{7}}{\left(1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7}\right)\tan\frac{\pi}{7}}$$
$$=1+\left(\frac{2\tan\frac{\pi}{7}}{1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7}}\right)\frac{1}{\tan\frac{\pi}{7}}$$
using $\color{blue}{\frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^2A}=\tan2A}$, 
$$=1+\frac{\tan\frac{2\pi}{7}}{\tan\frac{\pi}{7}}$$
$$=1+\frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos\frac{\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos\frac{\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}$$
using $\color{blue}{\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A=\sin(A+B)}$, 
$$=\frac{\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\left(\pi-\frac{3\pi}{7}\right)}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}$$
$$=\frac{2\cdot 2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}$$
$$=4\cos \frac{\pi}{7}$$
now, $RHS=\lambda\cos(\alpha)=\lambda\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$,

Now, equating LHS & RHS, we have $$4\cos\frac{\pi}{7}=\lambda\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$$ 
 $$\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{\color{blue}{\lambda=4}}$$

Answer (score -1):

Simply divide both sides of the equation by $\cos(\pi/7)$

$\lambda = \frac{3-\tan^2(\pi/7)}{\cos(\pi/7)(1-\tan^2(\pi/7)}$ = 3.999...

Comment: Give an explanation and procedure for this. Don't just use calculator and tell the answer.

Comment: The 'procedure' is just to divide by $\cos(\pi/7)$

Comment: I think he wants to get a numerical value of $\lambda$ without using a calculator to get $\tan(\pi/7)$. Something like a manipulation of trigonometric identities relating $\cos$ and $\tan$

Comment: You've only found an approximation, but not the exact simplified value.